# Flutter network image lazy loading

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have some questions.  How do make lazy loading video or photo from Firebase database like Instagram?
I am using `NetworkImage()` widget.

[image: here example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For lazy loading of the image you can check [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package. It provides progressIndicatorBuilder for showing the progress of the image load.

For example (taken from the library documentation),

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => 
            CircularProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress.progress),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
 ),
```

For video player can check [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) library.
If you want use caching feature for video also can check [cached_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_video_player), which is made extending the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package.